dot1x as networkmanager default for ethernet and wireless
we are enrolling ubuntu 24.04 in an environment with dot1x.
currently we prefconfigured networkmanager profiles usisng dot1x but when I use docking stations with integrated network card I always get networks cards whioch then would require dot1x configuration again.
Is it possible to set this config as a default for some ethernet types (obviously not all, since tunnel or vpn interfaces should not use dot1x)
Or even better: can I tell networkmanager to use the dot1x certificates as soon as it is requested by the switch or AP ?

What does "enrolling ubuntu 24.04 in an environment with dot1x" entail? What coommands did you try? What error messages did you see?

well what we currelty did was to create a networkmanager system connection like this: [802-1x]
ca-cert=/etc/ssl/certs/root.cer
client-cert=/etc/ssl/certs/foobar.crt
eap=tls;
identity=host/host.example.com
private-key=/etc/ssl/key/foobar.key
private-key-password=12345
We dont have a specific error, the question is how avoid to to this for every new connection
